# PHP: Count array items and then remove '../' foreach array item

Tags: php, laravel

Okay, a bit hard to explain but what I am trying to do is create a subheader for my site. The sub header will be based on the current URL lets use `sub/test/3rdleveldown/blog/post` as an example. What I need the subheader to do is, make a seperate link for each level of the url

Example: This would produce:

```html
<a href="../../../../sub">Sub</a> >> <a href="../../../test">Test</a> >> <a href="../../3rdleveldown">3rdleveldown</a> >> <a href="blog">blog</a>
```

This would allow the user to go down URL levels easily.

What I've managed to do is this

```
<div class="subheader">
  <?php
  $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $array = explode('/', $uri);
  $count = count($array);
  ?>
  @foreach ($array as $sub)
    <a href="NOW HERE I NEED TO ENTER the ../ based on how far down the link is in the array {{ $sub }}">{{ $sub }}</a> >>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

Can anybody help me get the `../` for each level down?

Comment: One question... why don't you use `blog` and `post` in your example? Why not `<a href="../../../../../sub">Sub</a> >> <a href="../../../../test">Test</a> >> <a href="../../../3rdleveldown">3rdleveldown</a> >> <a href="../../blog">Blog</a> >> <a href="../post">Post</a>` ? And what are the criteria for not using these parts?

Comment: No reason, I'll edit it now

Comment: Ah, okay! I almost posting an answer then.

Comment: And Post is not in it because it is the current page. The user doesn't need a link to it

Comment: I would recommend that you use absolute URLs instead of relative ones. This makes re-organizing a lot easier and is much better for SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, There's probably a better way to do it but this should do.

```
<div class="subheader">
  <?php
  $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $breadcrums = explode('/', $uri);
  array_pop($breadcrums);
  $count = count($breadcrums);
  --$count;
  $crumlevel = '';
  $ocount = $count;
  ?>
  @foreach ($breadcrums as $breadcrum)
  <?php
    for($count; !$count == 0 ; $count--){
      $crumlevel = '../'.$crumlevel;
    }
    $count = --$ocount;

  ?>
    <a href="{{ $crumlevel.$breadcrum }}">{{ $breadcrum }}</a> >>
    <?php $crumlevel = '../' ?>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like:

```
<?php

$path="sub/test/3rdleveldown/blog/post";
$arr = explode("/",$path);
array_pop($arr);
$sarr = sizeof($arr);

$count = 0;
$links = Array();

while ($count < $sarr) {
  $myhref = "<a href=\"";
  /*
   This will add the neccessary number of ../
  */
  for($i=1;$i<=($sarr-$count);$i++) $myhref .= "../";
  $myhref .= $arr[$count] . "\">" . ucfirst($arr[$count]) . "</a>";
  echo $myhref;
  array_push($links, $myhref);
  $count++;
}

print_r($links);

?>
```

Running this code you'll get

```
Array
(
    [0] => <a href="../../../../sub">Sub</a>
    [1] => <a href="../../../test">Test</a>
    [2] => <a href="../../3rdleveldown">3rdleveldown</a>
    [3] => <a href="../blog">Blog</a>
)
```

which is what you need, I believe.

Comment: I would simplify the code a little by using `str_pad()` instead of the `for`-loop

Comment: I noticed. Thanks! When I asked for it is because I do not code using PHP that much nowadays and I'm not used to some string functions as `str_pad`. I would like to see how you'd use it to make the same, just this.

Comment: I left PHP five years ago and now I use Ruby and Java most all the time.

Comment: I think this is the reason why my PHP code may seem a bit out-of-date now.

Comment: My mistake, I meant `str_repeat()`

Comment: Oh! Now I see it! In fact, you are right. It could be better with str_repeat!

Answer (score -1):

You can simply make a use of `segments` method on the `$request` variable.

```
$segments_arr = request()->segments();
// It would give you an array of URL sub-parts as: 
// ['Sub', 'test', '3rdleveldown'];
```

Then you can manipulate that array on your own. The trick of producing the links you're using is the one way or you can check out other Laravel Packages for creating Breadcrumbs.

**Update**

At the time of iterating through the segments array, you can create a link using request's `request()->root()`.

```
$root_path = request()->root();
foreach($segments_arr as $segment) {
    $href_str = $root_path . '/' . implode('/', array_slice($segments_arr, 0, $key + 1));
}
/* So for example if your root url is - www.example.com, then
    the output on $key = 0;

    www.example.com/segment1 --- $key = 0
    www.example.com/segment1/segment2 --- $key = 1
*/
```

Comment: I think he covered this part on his own already. What he needs is the part you are leaving out 'manipulate that array on your own'. What is left of your answer is the advice to use the breadcrumbs package, which is more a comment than an answer.